# affdex-sdk. How many frames can processed per second?

Tags: affdex-sdk

I used affdex android sdk, our device cpu is msm8994, android 6.0. but we used the sample apk framedectordemo, there only have 10 frames per second.  we want to know the official data. How many frames can processed per second?  from the affdex web sit, it said can reach to 20+ processed frames per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stated minimum requirements are a Quad-core 1.5 GHz Cortex-A53, 1 GB of RAM and Android 4.4 or better. As the MSM8994 uses a big.LITTLE configuration of 2 quad-core and the fast one is a 2.0Gz Cortex-A57 you should be able to achieve a good performance. If you don't want to modify the sample apk, you can just download AffdexMe from Google Play:　https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.affectiva.affdexme&hl=en and test the performance there. Remember that you can only track up to 6 detectors in AffdexMe, so if you are trying to benchmark the performance for a bigger amount of metrics the results are going to be different.

Comment: Dear Mr k,
    We used that apk,  it only have 6-7 frames per second.

Comment: I'm getting in between 5-6 fps in a smartphone using a Quad-core 1.5GHz Cortex-A53 like the one recommended in their webpage. The problem with AffdexMe, at least in the current Android version, is that you cannot select less than 6 metrics to check for the difference in performance. Selecting 3 or 4 detectors instead of 6 and using your MSM8994 it should be able to reach higher processing rates. Can you check if it's using the fast quad-core or the energy saving one?